# Modify URL in php

Tags: php

I want to modify following url http://www.gonzaga.edu/../../../../Files/About/Images/300x200/baseball_panorama_hz.jpg into http://www.gonzaga.edu/Files/About/Images/300x200/baseball_panorama_hz.jpg.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `str_replace`:

```
str_replace('../', '', $url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
$url="http://www.gonzaga.edu/../../../../Files/
About/Images/300x200/baseball_panorama_hz.jpg"

$url=str_replace('../','', $url);
```